# Modify JSON Object After Controller Returns

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using C# with MVC and trying to add data to a JSON message after the controller returns, but before it gets to the client.

*Is there a C# framework/tool I can use for that?*

**Example**

A controller returns order data for a particular order, which includes a date in Unix time (int representing seconds).

The message is intercepted before being returned to the caller.

Another field with Gregorian date/time converted from the Unix time is appended to the JSON message.

**Is this possible?**

Comment: Why not modify it on the server side controller then return it?

Comment: Check out [Action Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters)

Comment: So you want to return json data from your controller to the client? is this the question? Can you show your code or sample of data you want to return

Comment: if you are using Json.net, you can write a converter to do this when you serialize the data using DateTimeConverterBase.

Comment: @LG8 yes, do you need on all endpoints or only on specific ones?

Comment: @SilentTremor Ideally I would like to have this for all endpoints. It would be great if I could intercept the JSON message, inspect the message and determine the class type it represents, then selectively modify some fields based on the values of other fields. I would also need the object doing the manipulation to make service calls to determine some of the values/formatting.

Comment: @RyanWilson I have many controllers/methods that return various objects with a new date field nested at different levels with slightly different names. I really wanted to avoid adding dependencies and logic to many controllers if a framework existed which could find and replace fields in outgoing messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solution but **none of it are recommended!!!** both need to use reflection and recursion to parse and inject values on the result.

Main problem, how do you know a number is unix time span and not a number! In my example I compare if resulted date is between 2000 and current year.
One easy match would be to use a naming convention for Unix time spams, example:

```
public int UnixSaleDate {get; set;}
```

if a naming convention exist please change in bellow code snippet:

```
if (value.Type == JTokenType.Integer && IsValidDateTime(value)) // <= Change it
if (value.Type == JTokenType.Integer && name.Contains("Unix"))  // <= With these
```

> Option 1: WebApi Action filter

it's convenient for the fact that it can be specified on witch action to be used.

```
public class ActionInjectDateTimeFromUnixActionWebApiFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        var objectContent = actionExecutedContext.Response.Content as ObjectContent;
        if (objectContent != null)
        {
            //var type = objectContent.ObjectType; //type of the returned object
            var value = objectContent.Value; //holding the returned value
            var injection = RecursiveInjectUnixToDateTime(JObject.FromObject(value)); // recursively inject value
            objectContent.Value = injection;
            // Overwrite return value
            actionExecutedContext.Response.Content = objectContent;
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Recursive DateTime Injection 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">'obj' need to be a JObject</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private dynamic RecursiveInjectUnixToDateTime(JToken obj)
    {
        var expObj = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
        foreach (JProperty p in obj)
        {
            string name = p.Name;
            JToken value = p.Value;
            switch (value.Type)
            {
                case JTokenType.Integer:
                    {
                        // Make sure your int is a date time after, after all isn't sure you are returning an int or a UNIX date time
                        if (value.Type == JTokenType.Integer && IsValidDateTime(value))
                        {

                            expObj.Add(name + "_DateTime", UnixToDateTime((long) value));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            expObj.Add(name, value);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case JTokenType.Object:
                    {
                        // Go deep
                        // expObj[name] = RecursiveInjectUnixToDateTime(p.Value);
                        expObj.Add(name, RecursiveInjectUnixToDateTime(p.Value));
                    }
                    break;
                case JTokenType.Array:
                    {
                        // Go deep
                        var arr = new List<dynamic>();
                        foreach (var val in value.ToArray())
                        {
                            arr.Add(RecursiveInjectUnixToDateTime(val));
                        }
                        // expObj[name] = arr;
                        expObj.Add(name, arr);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    {
                        // expObj[name] = value;
                        expObj.Add(name, value);
                    }
                    break;

            }
        }



        return expObj;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validate if long value is a valid date time between 2000 and current year
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="longUnix"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool IsValidDateTime(JToken longUnix)
    {
        long unixDateTime = (long)longUnix;
        if (unixDateTime > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                var date = UnixToDateTime(unixDateTime);
                return date.Year >= 2000 && date.Year <= DateTime.UtcNow.Year;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private DateTime UnixToDateTime(long unixTimestamp)
    {
        DateTime unixYear0 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        long unixTimeStampInTicks = unixTimestamp * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;
        DateTime dtUnix = new DateTime(unixYear0.Ticks + unixTimeStampInTicks);
        return dtUnix;
    }
}
```

}

In controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [ActionInjectDateTimeFromUnixActionWebApiFilter]
        [Route("something1")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetSomething1()
        {
            return
                Ok(
                    new
                    {
                        unix = 1267480860,
                        some_int = 2,
                        obj = new
                        {
                            description = "Yah Right"
                        },
                        items = new List<object> {
                            new {
                                id = 1,
                                name = "dude",
                                unix2 = 1403473486
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [ActionInjectDateTimeFromUnixActionWebApiFilter]
        [Route("something2")]
        public Object GetSomething2()
        {
            return new
                    {
                        unix = 1267480860,
                        some_int = 2,
                        obj = new
                        {
                            description = "Yah Right"
                        },
                        items = new List<object> {
                            new {
                                id = 1,
                                name = "dude",
                                unix2 = 1403473486
                            }
                        }
                    };
        }
```

Response on both controller actions:

```
{
  "unix_DateTime": "2010-03-01T22:01:00",
  "some_int": 2,
  "obj": {
    "description": "Yah Right"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "dude",
      "unix2_DateTime": "2014-06-22T21:44:46"
    }
  ]
}
```

> Option 2: DelegatingHandler

witch is the worst possible solution!!! more details and how to 
[DelegatingHandler for response in WebApi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11970313/delegatinghandler-for-response-in-webapi)

Rest of the shebang, reuse-it from option 1 code snippet for date time injection (injection method).

Good luck, and chose wisely.

Comment: Thanks for the example! I was hoping that a framework existed that would allow me to easily update fields for a diverse range of message types. However it looks as if I'll have to try to work with each controller individually.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything to the data in C# after it has been returned from your controller. It's now going to the client. You'll either have to add a field to your class for the Gregorian time and initialize it before returning, or handle that on the client-side. It's pretty simple to add a field to an object in Javascript. Consider the following object:

```
var obj = {
   foo: "hello"
}
```

Now, let's add to this object. We have two choices:

```
obj.bar = "world" //Dot Notation
```

OR

```
obj["bar"] = "world" //Square Bracket Notation
```

For your case, it would make the most sense to use dot notation since the name of your variable will not be dynamically declared. As for calculating Gregorian time in Javascript, I recommend a useful library called moment.js, although it should be simple enough with the regular `Date()` object in JS.

With this being said, it's normally best practice to avoid doing things in JS that you can do on the backend. Making the browser do calculations that your server could easily do is just wasting the clients memory, taking up load time, and could cost you valuable traffic in the long run.

In order to calculate the UTC time from a Unix timestamp, it's pretty easy if you're using .Net 4.6. Assuming your unix timestamp is stored in a variable named 'myTimestamp':

```
DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(myTimestamp); //Offset from Unix epoch
DateTime dateTime = dateTimeOffset.UtcDateTime; //Gregorian
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. It looks like a Web Action Filter might allow for modifications after the controller returns.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can do something like below (add an extra property to represent Gregorian date/time):

```
public class MyModel
{
  public long UnixDateTime { get; set; }

  public DateTime GregorianDateTime { get { return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(UnixDateTime); } }
}
```

as stated by @Brandon you can use following code block for .NET 4.6 or above:

```
public DateTime GregorianDateTime { get { return DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(UnixDateTime).DateTime; } }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm really looking for a framework to modify messages after returning from the controller method.